# Ошибка: требуется объект "Folder"

Tags: vbscript

Я написал код, в которой функция `ListOfFolder` должна возвращать содержимое выбранной папки, но возникает ошибка:

> Требуется объект "Folder"

Не пойму, в чём дело.

```vb
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder("files")

Function ListOfFolder()
    Return Folder.SubFolders() & Folder.Files()
End Function
```

Comment: Что-то меня плюс смущает...

Comment: В документации явно написано, что если папка не существует, то возникнет ошибка. Если это не ваш случай и папка существует, то опишите подробнее, что значит "выбранной папки", кем выбранной, как выбранной, где она находится относительно файла и т.п.